# direnv cannot be removed by ```snap direnv remove```

Tags: direnv

Kubuntu 23.10

Install direnv by snap.

Set up .bashrc as required (eval "$(direnv hook bash)")

restarted the system

every time on entry to the directory, I received the error:

```
direnv: error .envrc is blocked. Run `direnv allow` to approve its content.
```

Following instructions typing `direnv allow` made no difference. Keep getting the same error.

Uninstalled direnv with

```
sudo snap remove direnv
direnv removed
bash: /snap/direnv/54/bin/direnv: No such file or directory
```

Then installed direnv via apt. No issues.

But, now on entry / exit and following every command executed inside the directory, the following error message shows:

```
bash: /snap/direnv/54/bin/direnv: No such file or directory
```

Clearly the snap remove has left some rubbish lying around.

Looking for help in cleaning up direnv snap install.